# Permutation representation contains trivial representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \vartriangleleft G$ a normal subgroup.

Let $(V,\rho)$ be the permutation representation (over $\mathbb{C})$ of $G$ acting on the set $G/H$ (we think of the quotient group as a set) in the natural way, *i.e.* for $s,t \in G$: $s \cdot (t\ (\textrm{mod}\ H)) = st\ (\textrm{mod}\ H)$.

Show that $(V,\rho)$ contains the trivial representation of $G$ with multiplicity 1.

My idea was to show that $G$ acts doubly transitively on $G/H$ and then apply [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327278/decomposition-of-permutation-representation).

But $G$ in particular need not act doubly transitively on itself, so we cannot apply this result.

Comment: It is essentially  the regular representation of $G/H$, and as such  it contains the trivial representation of $G/H$ with multiplicity one, and so when you regard it as a representation of $G$ the same applies. (As a regular representation it is never doubly transitive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $|H|$ elements with $|G/H|$ fixed points, and thus trace $|G/H|$, and all other elements have no fixed points and are thus traceless. Thus, by the [orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations), the multiplicity of the trivial representation $1$ in $\rho$ is

$$
\frac1{|G|}\sum_g\chi_1(g)\chi_\rho(g)=\frac1{|G|}\left(|H|\frac{|G|}{|H|}\right)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is with Frobenius Reciprocity and induction of characters. The permutation character equals $(1_H)^G$ and $[(1_H)^G, 1_G]=[1_H,1_H]=1$.